# AmChart second value axis display missbehaviour

Tags: javascript, axis, amcharts

I have an amChart with 2 value axis. When the `categoryAxis.autoWrap` is set to `true` and the label does not fit, the chart is not drawn correctly, the second value axis is out of view. When resizing the container, sometimes is ok, sometimes not.

Here is an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/phcdfbyt/4/).

Comment: This looks like a bug. Watch out for the new version of amCharts that fixes it.

Comment: In the meantime you can apply a temporary workaround of setting "marginRight" on your chart and "ignoreAxisWidth" on the right value axis: http://jsfiddle.net/hga2tmxj/

Comment: I got version 3.14, the latest now.

Comment: @martynasma Hi I am facing the same issue, but I cannot put marginRight as some fixed value. Is there any other fix we can do? Or can I calculate the margin right in some way?

Comment: @snehatulsi as far as I can tell the bug as not yet been fixed, I'm afraid.